# unable to start instance using python in aws using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
...    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
...    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')
```

Did this substituting values , when i run

```
  conn.run_instances('<ami-image-id>')
```

It gives an error stating

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_instances'

Comment: Is your AWS account new? I believe new accounts can no longer use EC2 Classic, but have to launch into VPCs instead. Hence, you'd need to add ``subnet_id=<subnet_id>`` to your run_instances call.

Comment: Your `conn` object is None, it failed to connect to the region - could be because of invalid credentials. After connecting, try to print conn, like this:

`>>> conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-1', aws_access_key_id='...', aws_secret_access_key='..')
>>> conn
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
`

Comment: Tried the connect to region it didn't work sumhow their was a problem with the terminal I restated the system and it worked !. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

The error output suggests that your `conn` variable is not being set.

Try running your `connect_to_region()` command directly and see what error messages are returned. Some possible explanations:

- Incorrect Access Key and/or Secret Key
- No connectivity from your computer to the US-West-2 Endpoint

Your **Access Key** should look something like: `AKIAJUWHFZOPPDM7B7XA`

Your **Secret Key** should consist of a string of 40 random characters.

If you are using boto from an EC2 instance that has a **Role** assigned, you do not need to pass through credentials. They will be automatically provisioned based upon the assigned Role, via the Instance Metadata Service.

Comment: Tried the connect to region it didn't work sumhow their was a problem with the terminal I restated the system and it worked !. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on my laptop (with an access key, secret key configured in my ~/.aws/config file) and it works as expected.

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
>>> conn.run_instances('ami-55a7ea65')
Reservation:r-a76255ac
```

A few things to check:

- Be sure your access key and secret key are correct
- Be sure your AMI ID matches an AMI for PV
- Be sure you have a default VPC for your account

Although in all these cases, the error message should have been more explicit, like :

> boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
>   
>   `InvalidParameterCombination`Non-Windows
>   instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not
>   supported for this instance
>   type.df213b43-e8e1-4cd5-9aa9-c4a9277588b8